# Call a Task Pane and close it from a ExecuteFunction button type

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I have an `ExecuteFunction` type button in my Excel Addin.
Based on user's selection when he clicks the button, I'd like to show a TaskPane (or not). Also, I'd like to close it later in case I opened it.

My scenario is: suppose the user selects only 10 cells, so the function will not take long to execute and I don't need to disturb him with a task pane in his screen because it'll be fast.

However, there may be cases where he selects an entire column and I need to show him a progress bar and additional information. So, I would need to call my generic progress bar task pane. After the progress bar finishes, it would be great to close it automatically.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API support yet to dynamically open and close task-panes. It is part of the backlog with no clear timeline. Please log your feature request here https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ for us to help track the interest level and also to communicate with interested developers when the plans become clear.

Comment: Thanks, Sudhi. I've found an uservoice suggestion to support it.
In case some reader land here and need this feature, this is the link: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/15114417-support-for-hiding-showing-task-pane-through-the-o